# Generating a bar code with the path to the data file with the pst-barcode package

Tags: pst-barcode

Here is a file that uses the pst-barcode package to generate a barcode. Namely, there is a need for files with ISBN numbers to be located in a separate folder and individual files.
The question is how to define the path to the file (for example, ISBN_2.txt) with the ISBN number in the \psbarcode command.

```
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}

%path to ISBN files
\def\ISBNPath{./input/ISBN_List}

\def\FileNumber{2}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(0,0)
\psbarcode{\input{\ISBNPath/ISBN_\FileNumber.txt}}{width=1.5 height=0.8}{isbn}
\end{pspicture}


\end{document}
```

If it is written as in the attached example, an error occurs when compiling the Latex file.

I'm sure someone knows the answer and the solution.
Please help and for one example.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following assumes you have a bunch of files `ISBN_#.txt` where `#` is some number and `ISBN_#.txt` contains a single ISBN that you want to print.

You have 3 options:

1. Ignore the files and enter the ISBN verbatim.
2. Use the `file` option with `\psbarcode` to identify that you're working with a file, not a verbatim barcode.
3. Capture the contents of `ISBN_#.txt` using [`catchfile`](//ctan.org/pkg/catchfile)'s `\CatchFileDef{<cmd>}{<file>}{}`, and the print the barcode using `\psbarcode{<cmd>}{<opts>}{}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\def\FileNumber{2}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)
  % 1. Input ISBN barcode verbatim
  %\psbarcode{978-3-16-148410-0}{width=1.5 height=0.8}{isbn}
  
  % 2. Input ISBN barcode from file
  \psbarcode[file]{ISBN_\FileNumber.txt}{width=1.5 height=0.8}{isbn}

  % 3. Capture ISBN barcode from file before printing
  %\CatchFileDef{\barcode}{ISBN_\FileNumber.txt}{}%
  %\psbarcode{\barcode}{width=1.5 height=0.8}{isbn}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Note that the files `ISBN_#.txt` should contain the ISBN only, no line feeds.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Everything you wrote was very helpful to me. You solved my problem. Thank you very much.